# How mint nft from policy_id

Tags: mesh, mintingpolicy

```
import { Transaction, ForgeScript } from '@meshsdk/core';
import type { Mint, AssetMetadata } from '@meshsdk/core';

// prepare forgingScript
const usedAddress = await wallet.getUsedAddresses();
const address = usedAddress[0];
const forgingScript = ForgeScript.withOneSignature(address);

const tx = new Transaction({ initiator: wallet });

// define asset#1 metadata
const assetMetadata1: AssetMetadata = {
  "name": "Mesh Token",
  "image": "ipfs://QmRzicpReutwCkM6aotuKjErFCUD213DpwPq6ByuzMJaua",
  "mediaType": "image/jpg",
  "description": "This NFT is minted by Mesh (https://meshjs.dev/)."
};
const asset1: Mint = {
  assetName: 'MeshToken',
  assetQuantity: '1',
  metadata: assetMetadata1,
  label: '721',
  recipient: 'addr_test1vpvx0sacufuypa2k4sngk7q40zc5c4npl337uusdh64kv0c7e4cxr',
};
tx.mintAsset(
  forgingScript,
  asset1,
);

const unsignedTx = await tx.build();
const signedTx = await wallet.signTx(unsignedTx);
const txHash = await wallet.submitTx(signedTx);
```

After mint nft. I have policy id, How mint new nft with policy_id